How to get a single entry per non-unique column value?
I have tables in DB and matching entities. I have a table 'products'. Each entry in 'products' has unique 'id' column and 'code', which is not unique, multiple different 'products' may have the same 'code'. I would like to write HQL query such that for each 'code' it will get me a single product (doesn't matter which one exactly). How can I achieve it?

Assuming you don't care which product id you return per unique code, you could use:
select prd.code, min(prd.id) as id
from Product prd
group by prd.code

The above would arbitrarily return the lowest id per unique code.
Edit: If you need the entire product entity, then use:
from Product prd1
where prd1.id in (
    select min(prd2.id)
    from Product prd2
    where prd2.code = prd1.code
)


No, I need the whole product object, not the id. I don't care for id.

@Taserface Check the edit
